# If I prove that $1/n^a \rightarrow 0$ does it mean that $1/n^n \rightarrow 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

If I prove that $ \frac 1 {n^a} \rightarrow 0 \ \ \forall α \in \mathbb N$ does it mean that $ \frac 1 {n^n}$ also tends to 0? I mean it obviously does but is it enough of a proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the question and comment thread in another answer, I'm not sure you are thinking about limits in the right way. This limit has $n$ approaching $\infty$, so in some sense $n$ is taking *all* the values $\{1,2,\ldots\}$. However the symbol $a$ represents *one* specific number.

If you prove $1/n^a$ approaches $0$, then you can *deduce* that $1/n^n$ does too by sandwiching $0<1/n^n<1/n^a$. But it's not as automatic as I think your question suggests.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: If $n \ge a \implies 0<\dfrac{1}{n^n} \le \dfrac{1}{n^a}$

Comment: I know that I can use the sandwich theorem I'm just asking if it's enough to say that if $1/n^α$ converges to zero then $1/n^n$ must also converge to zero.

Comment: i.e. say that α=n

Comment: $a$ is supposed to be a constant while $n$ varies.

Comment: Yes but since n is a natural number and α can be any natural number wouldn't it be ok?

Comment: $n/\alpha$ goes to infinity for all constants $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$ but $1$ certainly does not

Answer (score 1):

I can prove that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac an=0$$

for all $a\in\mathbb N$.

You seem to think this would imply that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac nn=0?$$

since we could have $a=n$.

However, it should be clear that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac nn=1\ne0$$